# Set keycloak default theme

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

Is there a way to set default Keycloak theme directly in the keycloak-server.json ? I tried below but it didnt work.

```html
    "theme": {
        "staticMaxAge": "${keycloak.theme.staticMaxAge:-1}",
        "cacheTemplates": "${keycloak.theme.cacheTemplates:false}",
        "cacheThemes": "${keycloak.theme.cacheThemes:false}",
        "folder": {
            "dir": "src/main/resources/themes"
        },
        "default": "KEYCLOAK_DEFAULT_THEME:custom"
    },
```